# How do I get shuffle() from Collections to not modify every array in a list?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I'm trying to get `Collections.shuffle()` to shuffle only one array is a list of 3 arrays made using `Collections.nCopies()` (ex: I only want it to shuffle the first array, but it ends up shuffling every array in the list)
Here's what I've done so far. I have been trying to look through Google for the same problem but the only examples provided are Strings or Integers, no Arrays.

`x` is `3` and `slotType.getSlotitems()` is for the array `["Apple","Cherry","Banana"]`

```
List<ArrayList<String>> q = Collections.nCopies(x,slotType.getSlotitems());

        for (ArrayList<String> v : q) {
            java.util.Collections.shuffle(v);
            System.out.println(v);
            System.out.println(q);
        }
```

The result that shows up is:

```
[Cherry, Banana, Apple]
[[Cherry, Banana, Apple], [Cherry, Banana, Apple], [Cherry, Banana, Apple]]
[Cherry, Banana, Apple]
[[Cherry, Banana, Apple], [Cherry, Banana, Apple], [Cherry, Banana, Apple]]
[Cherry, Apple, Banana]
[[Cherry, Apple, Banana], [Cherry, Apple, Banana], [Cherry, Apple, Banana]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nCopies` doesn't create copies of the element you pass to it, so `q` contains a `List` where the same `ArrayList<String>` instance is repeated `x` times. When you shuffle one of them, you shuffle all of them (since there is actually only one of them).

To create a `List` of `x` distinct copies, you can use Streams:

```
List<ArrayList<String>> q = 
    IntStream.range(0,x)
             .mapToObj(i -> new ArrayList<String>(slotType.getSlotitems()))
             .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now `shuffle` would only affect one of the `ArrayList`s.

Another option:

```
  List<ArrayList<String>> q =
      Collections.nCopies(x,slotType.getSlotitems())
                 .stream()
                 .map(ArrayList::new)
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here I took your original `List<ArrayList<String>>` (where all the elements are the same instance) and created a new `List<ArrayList<String>>` where each element is a copy of the original element.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for only getting back to you late, I had some trouble with my internet connection. It works perfectly.

Comment: Or `List<ArrayList<String>> q = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies( x,slotType.getSlotitems())); q.replaceAll(ArrayList::new);`